# Display and export data column wireshark

Tags: wireshark

I captured the modbus packets, and I want to know how can display my data in my columns to export as csv file later. I attach an image of the kind of data that I want to display and export

[image: 1]

Comment: I posted a sample of my data. I tried your command but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

For each field you want to add as a column, the easiest way is to first select the field, let's say the *"Function Code"* as an example.  When you select it, you'll notice the status line at the bottom of the Wireshark window will show you what the Wireshark display filter is for that field, and in this example, it'll be `modbus.func_code`.  This is one way to learn the display filter for a given field.

Now, if you right-click on the field, you can choose *Apply as Column*.  The field will be added as a new column.  Once added, you can drag and drop the field to any desired column location.  You can also add columns via the main menu, but if you add them this way, you'll have to know the Wireshark display filter name in order to type it in when adding it, which you can do by: *Edit -> Preferences -> Columns -> + -> [Double-click the default New Column title and rename it, double-click the default Number type and choose Custom, double click under Fields and type the display filter, e.g., modbus.func_code]*.

If you don't know the name of the display filter, you can look it up at least 3 differnet ways:

1. The Wireshark [Display Filter Reference](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/) page lists all display filters and which versions of Wireshark each display filter applies to.
2. From the Wireshark GUI: Edit -> *View -> Internals -> Supported Protocols -> Modbus -> [Expand]*
3. You can also use [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) to display them, for example:

On Windows:

```
tshark -G fields | findstr "modbus\."
```

On *nix:

```
tshark -G fields | grep "modbus\."
```

You can repeat this process for as many fields as you wish.  Before adding modbus-specific fields to the columns, it might be worthwhile to first create a new *"Modbus"* profile so those fields will only be shown as columns when you're examining modbus packets.  Add a new profile by right-clicking on the Profile in the lower-right corner of the status bar and choose *New* or *Manage Profiles*.  You can also add a new profile via the main menu: *Edit -> Configuration Profiles*.

I mentioned `tshark` above; it's the command-line equivalent of Wireshark, and it allows you to print only the fields you want, then you can redirect that output to a text file which can then be imported into other programs for further processing.  An example:

```
tshark -r file.pcap -Y "modbus" -T fields -E separator=/t -e frame.number -e modbus.func_code -e modbus.byte_cnt > file.txt
```

`tshark` has a lot of options, so be sure to read the man page for a better understanding of how to use it.

If you are not using `tshark`, then you export the data from the Wireshark GUI using: *File -> Export Packet Dissections -> As CSV... -> [Select/unselect desired options, choose a filename and click Save]*.

Finally, the Wireshark [User Guide](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/) is also a great reference.

Comment: Thanks Christopher. That's exactly what I'm looking for